# How to send a UIImage to Heroku?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, heroku, frontend

I found a code on here that let me send the image from my code to http/url, but every time I do it returns a 503. I'm not sure if it is my code from swift or my Heroku website that's not working? also if anyone has an easy way of sending a picture to a Heroku using swift please let me know.

Comment: What HTTP request library are you using? Could you share your code for that part?
- Also by saying Heroku do you mean a custom application code you hosted there? Because in that case you need to consult that application code to see how you can POST an image.

Comment: please do add sample code and output for a clear understanding of what you want to ask